# Why don't I get a warning when I declare a variable with same name in a macro that already exists in a function?

Tags: c, macros, ansi-c

Playing with a macro and thought about the following scenario. Declaring variable in a macro which already exists in function from which this macro has been called, why compiler doesn't complain. When I declare in a code a variable it give me a warning:

> Redefinition of 'temp'

I think that it's intended behavior and have to be documented in the standard (ANSI C), but couldn't find where.

For example this code:

```
#define TEST() { \
    int temp = 10; \
}

int main() {

    int temp = 999;

    printf("\ntemp: %d", temp);
    TEST();
    printf("\ntemp: %d", temp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code and the macro above, the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) generates the following:

```
int main() {

  int temp = 999;

  printf("\ntemp: %d", temp);
  { 
    int temp = 10; 
  }
  printf("\ntemp: %d", temp);
}
```

This is the code that the C compiler receives.

The inner `{ .. }` is called a [*nested scope*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#C). In your case this nested inner scope contains a variable `temp`, of which there is already one in the surrounding outer scope ([*variable shadowing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)). And that triggers the warning you're seeing.

Note: in your particular example, the `temp` variable is declared in a nested scope, never used, and the scope closes thus removing that variable. It's essentially a [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP).

Answer (score 2):

The macro expands to a block. Inside the block is a separate scope, where you can declare variables with the same name as outside. They will shadow the outer variables. Doing this is usually not a good idea.

Comment: What do you mean doing this? Doing a macro with a variable which already used inside a function?

Comment: @Anatoly: with "doing this" Sebastian refers to "shadowing variables". If you receive a warning like that then it's a good idea to clean up your code, because shadowing can be the cause of bugs and headache.